# How to remove scroll bar from fullscreen Console in C#?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, scrollbar, fullscreen

Long story short: I just picked up C# about a week ago. Most of my programming knowledge comes from Java. I want to try my hand at making a text adventure game (yes I know I can used Unity, but I want to make it from scratch) and part of the setup is getting a full screen Console window with no distractions.

I've scavenged about on StackOverflow and so far I've put this together:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleDisplayMode(IntPtr ConsoleOutput, uint Flags, out COORD NewScreenBufferDimensions);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;

        public COORD(short X, short Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    }
```

Alongside this bit in the Main method:

```
IntPtr hConsole = GetStdHandle(-11);
SetConsoleDisplayMode(hConsole, 1, out COORD b1);

Console.ReadLine();
```

So I've managed to get in full screen successfully, but problem is a scroll bar is still there.

I've done my best to understand exactly how this works and how the scroll bar would be removed. My current understanding is that the Console's screen buffer needs to be changed to match the size of the screen so that the scroll bar can disappear.

From the code I managed to put together, it seems that the buffer is already being played with in order to go full screen. Looks like the 'SetConsoleDisplayMode' method does that.

So my question is, how do I add in the removal of the scroll bar to this code? My mind is saying it has something to do with the 'COORD' struct but honestly I'm totally out of my element here with a new language and new  concepts (like structs), any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A struct is just a collection of variables under one name. So you're dealing with two short variables named X and Y that are bundled into one block for easy transfer and reference. A short is a short; it's a signed 8-bit integer variable with a range of -128 to 127. The [MSDN documentation for SetConsoleDisplayMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoledisplaymode) tells you what the parameters are that it accepts and what they do or mean.

Comment: Have you tried changing Console.BufferHeight ?

Answer (score 1):

this class is defineatly work for you it full screen automatically the console and remove the scroll bars the clear and black console screen is appers only and you do what  ever you want
 ##

```
public class SetLayout
{
    // Control the console whole setting
    public void Set()
    {
        Console.SetBufferSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);               // Remove the console both scroll bars

        IntPtr hConsole = FullScreen.GetStdHandle(-11);                                                // Get console handle
        FullScreen.COORD xy = new FullScreen.COORD(100, 100);
        FullScreen.SetConsoleDisplayMode(hConsole, 1, out xy);                                       // Set the console to fullscreen

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);        //  Set to not show the "Press any key to continue"

        Console.CursorVisible = false;                                                           // Remove the cursor from the console
    }

    // Handler Method to remove the "Press any key to continue........."
    void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FullScreen.ShowWindow(FullScreen.ThisConsole,0);
    }
}

// Class is setting the console window full screen
internal static class FullScreen
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
        public COORD(short x, short y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleDisplayMode(IntPtr ConsoleOutput, uint Flags, out COORD NewScreenBufferDimensions);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    public static IntPtr ThisConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
}
```

you just have to write in  the main method :

SetLayout s  = new SetLayout();
s.Set();

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar will disapear when your buffer height is equal to your screen height (in Lines). You can test that with a noraml `cmd.exe` window.

When you make your console fullscreen, Windows will make your Buffer bigger if it was too small and return the new size in the last argument of
[`SetConsoleDisplayMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoledisplaymode). You probably need that size as you progress with your project. So if you make the buffer really small Windows fill "fix" it for you.

In order to change your buffer size you will need to call [`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize):

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ COORD  dwSize
);
```

That will look like this (untested):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(int handle, COORD newSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't manage to do it that way, though it definitely seems like the way to go. I'll need to read up more on WinAPI stuff. In the meantime, I've managed to make it work like this:

Console.SetBufferSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth - 3, Console.LargestWindowHeight);